# VMWare ESXi v4.1 - Convert Mps Uniprocessor To Acpi

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi

On most of my VM's the CPU is setup as ACPI Uniprocessor (see below)[image]. Some of my VM's are setup as MPS Uniprocessor. I need to change it to ACPI, so I can upgrade to Server 2008. How to I change it?

Comment: Are these machines all the same virtual machine version? I believe version 7 is current.

Comment: They are both hardware version 4

Comment: All my VM's are set to hardware Version 4

Comment: Do I have to replace the HAL.dll, get a driver or what can I do? When I try "update driver" it does not give me the choice for ACPI..

Comment: Frankly, I haven't a clue. I would recommend, though, getting your machines updated to version 7. There are several very nice additions that you'll get.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246236 http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-hardware-abstraction-layer.html http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q234558

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a VMWare ESX issue at all, this is purely down to Windows and your current hardware platform and the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) chosen during the initial install of Windows.

With Windows 2003 the HAL type is a choice made **forever** (you can make minor changes after this point, sometimes, but really consider this a decision that is locked down for the life of the system at this point) during the install process - by the installer itself if you don't specify one. This is documented by Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309283) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299340).

As I recall, there is no supported way to change the HAL type in the way you want after install, so you may need to do a clean install and migrate data that way. Frankly, even if there is some clever hack that I've missed, a clean install and migration is the only way I'd produce a result I would personally trust from this starting point.

Comment: I have seen tricks back in the Windows 2000 days to change the HAL, but doing them tended to cause problems.  A clean install is the way to go.

Comment: I ended up doing repair install and choosing F5 -> ACPI Multiprocessor PC and it works fine! Since this is ONLY an intranet IIS Test machine, I feel safe doing this. Let's see how stable it is..

Comment: @Zoredache - I helped write the documentation for most of the NT4 and Windows 2000 HAL changing tricks for Microsoft... it's certainly possible. Just not, as you say, likely to work without problems.

Comment: @IT_Fixr - glad its working for you but I agree with you about only using this approach for test machines. There's no way in hell I'd do this on a live 'production' machine...

Comment: I looked at our company KDB and this method has been proven on many machines.

Comment: I had another VM (on esxi 4, hardware 4) that I was upgrading from server 2000 to 2003, so when it reboots the first time and says "starting windows install.. Hit F6 for scsi.." I hit F5 and choose ACPI Multiprocessor PC and the VM has been 100% stable!